# https connection on local machine

Tags: php, apache, https, lamp

Receiving below error while trying to connect https on local mechine. I am using **lampstack 5.5**.

```
The connection to localhost:8443 was interrupted while the page was loading
```

Answer (score 0):

HTTPS use SSL certificates that are typically contains domain name. So if you want use HTTPS for local communication you need either certificate issued for localhost or use fully qualified domain name from existing certificate.